# Style loss is always zero

Tags: python, pytorch, styles, loss-function

I am trying to use feature reconstruction and style reconstruction losses on my model. For this, I followed the example code on PyTorch website for “Neural Style Transfer”.

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/neural_style_tutorial.html

Although the feature loss is calculated without problem, the style loss is always zero. And I could not find the reason since everything looks fine in the implementation. The calculation methods are the same as the proposed mathematical methods for these loss functions. Besides, as you know, the style and feature losses are almost the same in terms of calculation except Gram matrix step in style loss and no problem in feature loss.

Could anyone help me with this situation?

```
class Feature_and_style_losses():
def __init__(self, ):
    self.vgg_model = models.vgg19(pretrained=True).features.cuda().eval()
    self.content_layers = ['conv_16']
    self.style_layers = ['conv_5']

def calculate_feature_and_style_losses(self, input_, target, feature_coefficient, style_coefficient):
    i = 0
    feature_losses = []
    style_losses = []
    for layer_ in self.vgg_model.children():
        if isinstance(layer_, nn.Conv2d):
            i += 1
            name = "conv_{}".format(i)

            if name in self.content_layers:
                features_input = self.vgg_model(input_).detach()
                features_target = self.vgg_model(target).detach()
                feature_losses.append(self.feature_loss(features_input, features_target))
            if name in self.style_layers:
                style_input = self.vgg_model(input_).detach()
                style_target = self.vgg_model(target).detach()
                style_losses.append(self.style_loss(style_input, style_target))

    feature_loss_value = (torch.mean(torch.from_numpy(np.array(feature_losses, dtype=np.float32)))) * feature_coefficient
    style_loss_value = (torch.mean(torch.from_numpy(np.array(style_losses, dtype=np.float32)))) * style_coefficient

    return feature_loss_value, style_loss_value

def feature_loss(self, input_, target):
    target = target.detach()
    feature_reconstruction_loss = F.mse_loss(input_, target)
    return feature_reconstruction_loss

def gram_matrix(self, input_):
    a, b, c, d = input_.size() #??? check size
    features = input_.view(a*b, c*d)
    #features_t = features.transpose(1, 2)
    #G = features.bmm(features_t) / (b*c*d)
    #print(features.shape)
    G = torch.mm(features, features.t())
    return G.div(a*b*c*d)
    return G

def style_loss(self, input_, target):
    G_input = self.gram_matrix(input_)
    G_target = self.gram_matrix(target).detach()
    #style_reconstruction_loss = self.feature_loss(G_input, G_target)
    style_reconstruction_loss = F.mse_loss(G_input, G_target)
    return style_reconstruction_loss
```

---

```
feature_loss_ = Feature_and_style_losses()
...
for e in range(epochs):
    for i, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
        ...
        real_C = Variable(batch["C"].type(Tensor))
        fake_C = independent_decoder(features_all)    
        f_loss, s_loss = feature_loss_.calculate_feature_and_style_losses(fake_C, real_C, 1, 10)
        loss_G_3 = loss_GAN_3 + lambda_pixel * (loss_pixel_3_object + loss_pixel_3_scene) * 0.5 + f_loss + s_loss
        loss_G_3.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer_independent_decoder.step()
```

Best.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: I edited my post and included the code.

Comment: The loss looks correct, can you include your whole training pipeline?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. During training, I just called calculate_feature_and_style_losses(fake_image, real_image) function which returns feature loss correctly. But style loss is always zero. The inputs are correct as well. Because I used them in different loss functions and feature loss as well. I included corresponding part of the code.

Comment: Are you calling optimizer_independent_decoder.zero_grad() in your training loop?

Comment: Yes, of course. There is no problem in the training part since all of the loss functions are calculated correctly and the network performance is fine.

Comment: What are you doing here: feature_loss_value = (torch.mean(torch.from_numpy(np.array(feature_losses, dtype=np.float32)))) * feature_coefficient ? Why do you convert "feature_losses" to a numpy array and then back to a pytorch tensor? You cannot propagate gradients though that operation.

Comment: Okay, then I will directly convert the list to PyTorch tensor using "torch.tensor(feature_losses)". I think it will be convenient way. However, it is not the reason of the zero value.